# Tab Key not moving my cursor from field to field on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I created an HTML5 webapp consisting in a table with one  per , each line containing 7 s. Each field value is then sent by AJAX to a PHP script.

I'm sort of stucked with this : in order to navigate between form  fields, I'm used to hit the key tab, but on IE, this won't work. Instead, the focus seems to fade away (maybe moving to the  ?), and if I hit the Tab key one more time, it returns to the same  field.

I tried to detect the focused element with jQuery using the $(':focus') in the console selector, but with no chance, since clicking on the console leads me to the body DOM object ...

The mechanism works very well on the other browsers.

Thanks for your help,

Jérémie

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add a tabindex to your input fields?

```
            <form action="/Home/Review" name="reviewForm" method="post">
            <ul class="vertical-list form-inputs">
                <li>
                    <label class="input-label" for="ReviewerName">Your Name</label>
                    <input placeholder="Your Name" id="ReviewerName" tabindex="1" name="ReviewerName"
                           autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" required autofocus />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="input-label" for="ReviewerEMail">E-Mail</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Your E-Mail" id="ReviewerEMail" tabindex="2"
                           name="ReviewerEMail" required
                           autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" title="Please Enter Your E-Mail" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="input-label" for="ReviewerPhone">Phone</label>
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" id="ReviewerPhone" tabindex="3"
                           pattern="\(\d\d\d\) ?\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d" title="(###) ###-####"
                           required name="ReviewerPhone"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="input-label" for="ReviewText">Review</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Enter Your Review" tabindex="4" id="ReviewText"
                              autocorrect="on" required name="ReviewText"></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div id="reviewCancel" class="btn review-cancel" tabindex="6">Cancel</div>
                    <button type="submit" id="reviewSubmit" class="btn review-submit" tabindex="5">Submit</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

Comment: do you have a public url you can share or maybe setup a jsFiddle?